# How do I change the font of an axis in a waterfall chart

Tags: excel, vba

I need to change the color, name, and size of tickmarks on a waterfall chart. When I reference the ticklabels object, as I have done with other chart types, it fails with 445-Object doesn't support this action. Any suggestions?

Here's the code:

```
    Dim axisFontColor&, axisFontSize%
    axisFontColor = RGB(64, 64, 64)
    axisFontSize = 10
        
    Dim eoFontName$
    eoFontName = "Segoe UI"

    cht.Axes(xlValue).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = eoBlack 'SUCCESS
    cht.Axes(xlValue).Format.Line.Weight = xlHairline 'SUCCESS
    cht.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font.name = eoFontName 'FAILURE
    cht.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font.Size = axisFontSize 'FAILURE
    cht.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font.Color = axisFontColor 'FAILURE
    
    cht.Axes(xlCategory).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = eoBlack 'SUCCESS
    cht.Axes(xlCategory).Format.Line.Weight = xlHairline  'SUCCESS
    cht.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.name = eoFontName 'FAILURE
    cht.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Size = axisFontSize 'FAILURE
    cht.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Color = axisFontColor 'FAILURE
    cht.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Bold = False
```

Thanks for your help,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**,

May **explicit values** should be specified for those `variables` mentioned in the code.

```
Sub Bouton1_Clic()

' You can put values for those variables here
axisFontSize = 16
eoFontName = "Consolas"
axisFontColor = rgbRed

Set cht = Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Chart
    cht.Axes(xlValue).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = eoBlack
    cht.Axes(xlValue).Format.Line.Weight = xlHairline
    cht.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font.Name = eoFontName
    cht.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font.Size = axisFontSize
    cht.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font.Color = axisFontColor
    
    cht.Axes(xlCategory).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = eoBlack
    cht.Axes(xlCategory).Format.Line.Weight = xlHairline
    cht.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Name = eoFontName
    cht.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Size = axisFontSize
    cht.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Color = axisFontColor
    cht.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Bold = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks I have updated the variable declarations and value setting